# MSTeams Store auth token after tabs authentication flow

Tags: microsoft-teams

I've put together the authentication flow for Tabs with the signin start page, end page and getting the token back from my Identity Provider (Cognito in this case)

Now I have this token. Initially, I figured I'd simply store it in localStorage and refer to it, but it seems that Teams clears the storage everytime you refresh a Tab.

As a result, my user gets the login flow again when they switch tabs.

How do you store the token (or ANY info for that matter) to access from all tabs? Or from chats? Bots?

How about Bots info if the token is obtained through the Bot OAuth card?

The examples are so unclear and not even close to the code given by the MS Teams Toolkit from VSCode...

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Could you please check this [sample](https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-sample-complete-node) as reference to handle the token and authentication.

Comment: I have, multiple times. As specified above, the samples are extremely convoluted for such simple tasks. In the case of tabs, for instance, I litterally have my token. Cognito sent it back. I even put together a React context to test and store it in the app. As soon as I switch tabs or refresh the page, my context is emptied and I lose my token. Hence my question.

Comment: This is what I used to scaffold the code: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TeamsDevApp.ms-teams-vscode-extension I figured hey, it's made by MS for an MS App, it will be easy to use....